# Writing a regex in perl to compare a method definition in java

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I want to compare method definition like :

```
1. static void main(String[] args){

2. static void main(String[] args)
{
3. int sum()
4. int abc(int a,int b){
```

I just have the method's name and I'm reading the file one line at a time.

The regex shouldn't compare method calls such as :

```
sum();
OBJ.abc(1,2);
```

I wrote a regex which is not working :

```
$srcLine =~ m/$methodName[\([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*\s*[,]*\(*\)*\)]*/)
```

I'm getting a compilation error at this line.

**EDIT**

```
$srcLine =~ m/$methodName\((?!~)+\)/
```

This is another regex where I am comparing it with the 
"methodName('anything other than ~')"

Comment: The question is hard to understand. A regex doesn't "compare" things; it either matches or doesn't match them. The "compare" part makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how restrictive your pattern should be, but I can explain you the problems in your regexes.

1. `$srcLine =~ m/$methodName[\([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*\s*[,]*\(*\)*\)]*/)`

   With the square brackets you are creating a character class and you can't mix them. So I assume you wanted a group there, so

   ```
   $srcLine =~ m/$methodName(?:\([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*\s*[,]*\(*\)*\))*/)
   ```

   would be a bit closer at your requirements. I am not sure about the `[,]*` part, that means match a literal "," 0 or more times, this is probably not what you want.
2. `$srcLine =~ m/$methodName\((?!~)+\)/`

   You can't repeat a zero width assertion (the `(?!~)+` part). If you want to say match anything but a certain character, use a negated character class.

   ```
   $srcLine =~ m/$methodName\([^~]+\)/
   ```

   Be aware that this will match till the last found closing bracket.

Comment: `$srcLine =~ m/$methodName\(.*\)[^;]/`
I used the [^;] to consider if a **;** occurs at the end to omit `abc();`. Works fine for that but it also omitting `void abc()`, I cant figure out why.
Thank you for your previous answer.